# How to fetch data properly from route params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have one 'main' route with current data presented and another route with 'favorites'
when user click on a favorite component im sending him to the main route and need to present the new data fetched from an api and updating via redux.

So im using the code below in the main component , but what i get is that the previous data is presented for a few second and only then it changes :

```
  async componentWillMount(){
        let {cityName} = this.props.match.params
        if (cityName) return await this.props.onDataLoad(cityName)
        if (!dailyForecasts) await 
  this.props.onDataLoad(this.state.defaultCity) 
    }
```

How can i avoid this behavior ?

Comment: Does the same component present both of the routes? does the same store/reducer hold the data for both of the component/s?

Comment: You'll basically need to empty the store which holds the data once the user switches to the favourites route. maybe via `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: If the component is the same, it render old data since api has fetched new data. PS: use ```componentDidMount()```.